# How to check if key doesn't exist in yml-file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a conditional for

```
t(foo.bar)
```

that returns false if foo.bar doesn't exist and true if it does exist in the yml-file, like this.

```
foo:
  bar: here
```

Comment: you mean this? `if (t(foo.bar)) # do something end`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `I18n.t!` and rescue the `I18n::MissingTranslationData` exception it raises if the key is missing:

```
def translation_exists?(key)
  begin
    I18n.t!(key)
    true # or just return the result of t! as it's truthy.
  rescue => I18n::MissingTranslationData
    false
  end
end
```